# Does Google App Engine charge for a stopped service?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I deployed an app to GAE in the Flex environment and after playing around for a while, I stopped the service from serving requests (did not disable the app though). Will I still be charged for anything?

Comment: Most likely, application instances are still running in Docker containers on Compute engine. Perhaps consider [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/blog/topics/developers-practitioners/lifecycle-container-cloud-run). You do not pay for idle containers on Cloud Run.

Comment: I'm assuming you mean that no Version of your App Engine Flexible environment (AEF) Service has any Instances.  If you head on over to the AEF pricing page, [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-pricing), it seems as if you _may_ still be charged for anything saved to a Compute Engine (GCE) persistent disk.  To check and make sure, head on over to the Billing section of the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Console [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing), select your project and compare your current GAE cost to the forecasted cost for the rest of the month.

Comment: When a Flex service is stopped, the underlying GCE resources are removed, so you will not be charged for them.  However, if you stored anything in Cloud Storage (GCS), you will be charged at normal GCS rates, even if your service is stopped (this is also true if you [disable your app](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/managing-projects-apps-billing#disabling_an_application)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [Pricing Page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing#flexible-environment-pricing), App Engine is only billed by running instances. In the specific case of GAE Flex for the VM underneath.

Therefore if the service is stopped it will scale down to zero and its compute resources will get deleted. Therefore it shall not generate any charges as a stopped service has no running instances.

However keep in mind that `default` service cannot be stopped and to stop that particular service you would need to disable the App.

Comment: Per the [App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/the-appengine-environments#compare_high-level_features) services in the Flex environment do not scale to 0.  The only time a Flex service will not have any instances running is if it is stopped.

Also, you can stop the `default` service (or any other service) as long as it is a Flex service, or a Standard service using Manual or Basic scaling.

Comment: About scaling to zero it only scales to zero if the sevice is stopped(never while serving), I have actually done this in a project for myself.